# How do I serialize this JSON format by JAXB Annotation Class?

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

I am looking JAXB annotation class which can be serialized the following json format.
JSON Format : `{"name":"xyz","attr1":"attr1value","attr2":"attr2value",.....}}`
In above JSON format, name is a mandatory attribute,
others are not but user should be able to pass as much as attributes.

The below JaxB annotation class which can be serialized the JSON format
`{"name":"xyz","openContentMap":{"attr1":"attr1value","attr2":"attr2value", so on}}`.
But we want to JaxB annotation which can be serialized this format `{"name":"xyz","attr1":"attr1value","attr2":"attr2value",.....}}`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyJaxbBean  {

private String name;
private Map<String, String> openContentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

@XmlAnyElement
public Map<String, String> getOpenContentMap() {
    return openContentMap;
}

@XmlAnyElement
public void setOpenContentMap(String key, String value) {
    openContentMap.put(key, value);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public MyJaxbBean() {   
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter` and `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyJaxbBean
{
   private String name;

   private Map<String, String> openContentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   @JsonAnyGetter
   public Map<String, String> getOpenContentMap()
   {
      return openContentMap;
   }

   @JsonAnySetter
   public void add(final String key, final String value)
   {
      openContentMap.put(key, value);
   }
}
```

works well

```
  String json = "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"attr1\":\"attr1value\",\"attr2\":\"attr2value\"}";
  MyJaxbBean agr = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyJaxbBean.class);
  System.out.println(agr.getName() + " " + agr.getOpenContentMap());
```